# Set value of --args from within R session

Tags: r, evaluate, cran, rscript

I would like to use the `evaluate` package to simulate executing (lots of) r-scripts while recording the outputs using evaluate. Evaluate is designed to do exactly this and it works almost out of the box. However, when using Rscript, the user passes arguments via the command line `--args` which are retrieved in R using the `base::commandArgs` function.

Is there any sensible way I can override the value of `--args` from within a running R session such that an R script using `base::commandArgs()` would work as expected without having to modify the script itself?

Comment: Why not to set your args in your current session? ie Type in the console `args <- c(arge1,arg1,...)`

Comment: I would like it to work for 3rd party r-scripts.

Comment: I don't get your point. What I mean you just comment one line in your script `#args <- commandArgs(TRUE)` then you define `args` in your console and you `source('script_name')`.

Comment: Assume i have 10000000 scripts from other people that might or might not use `commandArgs` somewhere and I want to run them.

Comment: I can't assume anything. If you have 10000000  scripts to run You add this information to your question. And how do you will test arguments for 10000000 scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a delve into R's guts and came up with some smelly intestines to play with.

The command line is copied from C's argc/argv into a global C variable with this function in the source code:

```
void R_set_command_line_arguments(int argc, char **argv)
```

So we need a little C wrapper to get round the fact that the first parameter isn't a pointer:

```
#include "R.h"
#include "R_ext/RStartup.h"
void set_command(int *pargc, char **argv){
  R_set_command_line_arguments(*pargc, argv);
}
```

compile in the usual way:

```
R CMD SHLIB setit.c
```

load, call:

```
> dyn.load("setit.so")
> commandArgs()
[1] "/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R"
> invisible(.C("set_command",as.integer(2),c("Foo","Bar")))
> commandArgs()
[1] "Foo" "Bar"
```

from then on `commandArgs()` will return that vector until you change it.

Comment: even if All this smells not very good :) but good to know how to hack some R'C code.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the @spacedman answer as a simple Rcpp-based implementation.  We have to do some gymnastics on the on the vector to get it into `char**` format:

```
#include "Rcpp.h"
#include "R_ext/RStartup.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void setCmdArgs(std::vector<std::string> x) {
  std::vector<char*> vec(x.size());
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<x.size(); i++) 
    vec[i] = const_cast<char*>(x[i].c_str());
  R_set_command_line_arguments(x.size(), static_cast<char**>(&(vec[0])));
}

/*** R
setCmdArgs(c("hello", "world"))
commandArgs()
setCmdArgs(c("good", "bye", "my", "friend"))
commandArgs()
*/
```

If you save this in a file and pull it in via a single call to `sourceCpp()`, then the R
snippet at the bottom is executed too:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/spacedman.cpp")

R> setCmdArgs(c("hello", "world"))

R> commandArgs()
[1] "hello" "world"

R> setCmdArgs(c("good", "bye", "my", "friend"))

R> commandArgs()
[1] "good"   "bye"    "my"     "friend"
R>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your script you set `commandArgs` to be `TRUE`, if you don't pass anything on the command line the variable will be of length `0` so use an `if` statement to assign some values when you are not actually passing command line arguments. If you need to be careful about using default values you can set a flag to print a message when you use default values of command line args.

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
argDefault <- FALSE
if( length(args) == 0 ){
   args <- whatever you want
   argDefault <- TRUE
}
res <- 2 * args[1]
if( argDefault )
      simpleWarning(message="No command args were passed: Use of default values")
```

Comment: @agstudy thanks for the tip with `simpleWarning`, I didn't know about this before. Cheers!

Comment: This does not really solve my problem. I am executing (lot of) third party supplied r-scripts that expect input via `commandArgs`.