# How do I run R scripts with arguments from the R prompt?

Tags: r

Suppose I have an R script called `foo.r`. 
Normally I would run it as `Rscript foo.r <args>`.

How would I run the same script from the interactive `R` prompt from running `R` on the command line?

Comment: (Untested): `system()`?

Comment: @joran's suggestion _does_ work: `cat("#!/usr/bin/env Rscript\ncommandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)", file="foo.R");system("Rscript foo.R some args")`

Answer (score 2):

If it is the case that you need to run this script both interactively and non-interactively I would add some logic like this:

```
if( interactive() ) {
    args <- strsplit(readline("Enter Args: "), " ")
} else {
    args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
}
```

Basically, if the script is being run interactively prompt user for a command option string that you will then parse somehow so that `args` is set in the same way as it would be from whatever command line parsing you are using now.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/interactive.html

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a duplicate. First use one of the solutions from:

[Set value of --args from within R session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206567/set-value-of-args-from-within-r-session/17221560#17221560)

to set the `commandArgs()`, then `source("foo.R")`.